# Бот голосование discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет, в общем нужен бот который каждый день будет отправлять два сообщения, к примеру одно в 15:00, проставлять реакции. Считать их количество и подводить итоги голосования во втором сообщении, допустим в 17:00. Все без сторонних команд, чтобы оно было все автономно. У меня вышел маленький огрызок, так как не обладаю знаниями достаточными, но как-то получается так.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")




async def func():
    c = bot.get_channel(799262729742319616) # замени потом
    msg = ("""@everyone 
️ В 18:00 по МСК игровая сессия.
Голосование за ИЗ, погоду, время и температуру:
 Игровая зона: Los Santos - :LS: : Blaine County - :BC:
 Время 8:00 AM - :Morning: ; 3:00 PM - :Day: ; 8:00 PM - :Evening: ; 1:00 - :Night:
️ Погода: Ясно- :sun:  ;Шторм - :storm: ;Облачно - :Cloudy: ;Пасмурно - :rain:
️ Температура: 15°С (59 °F)-:Frog: ; 25°C (77 °F)- :Pepega: ; 33°C (91°F)-:pepe_high:
️ Итоги будут подведены в 17:00 по МСК""")
    await c.send(msg)

    
@bot.command()
async def getmsg(ctx, msgID: int): 
    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msgID)
    total_count = 0
    for r in msg.reactions:
        total_count += r.count
    print(total_count)
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await msg.add_reaction("<\U0001f1e6>")
    await msg.add_reaction("<\U0001f600") # временно пока добавляю обычный эмодзи
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

    #initializing scheduler
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    #sends "текст" to the channel when time hits 
    scheduler.add_job(func, CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="15", minute="00", second="00"))

    scheduler.add_job(getmsg, CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="17", minute="00", second="00"))
    
    #starting the scheduler
    scheduler.start()


        
bot.run("ТОКЕН")
```

Должно получаться что-то типо этого:
[image: пример]

Answer (score 0):

В общем, с божьей помощью я написал это самостоятельно и если кому-то нужен код, то держите. В случае если при голосовании одинаковое число, бот выберет вариант самостоятельно.
Пример работы:

[image: пример]

КОД:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
from discord.ext import commands
import random

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

async def func():
    c = bot.get_channel(ID канала) # замени потом
    msg = ("""@everyone 
️ В 18:00 по МСК игровая сессия.
Голосование за ИЗ, погоду, время и температуру:
 Игровая зона: Los Santos - <:15:895358200168206367> : Blaine County - <:seb:895330238249201725>
 Время 8:00 AM - <:10:895358262139039764> ; 3:00 PM - <:11:895358263456067585> ; 8:00 PM - <:12:895358264286511155> ; 1:00 AM - <:1_:895358254396371005>
️ Погода: Ясно- <:2_:895358262269071441>  ;Шторм - <:3_:895358257735016479> ;Облачно - <:4_:895358262185173013> ;Пасмурно - <:5_:895358257047167006>
️ Температура: 15°С (59 °F)- <:6_:895358259337236512> ; 25°C (77 °F)- <:7_:895358262730424330> ; 33°C (91°F)- <:8_:895358263116304484>
️ Итоги будут подведены в 17:00 по МСК""")
    await c.send(msg)
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID КАНАЛА)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(channel.last_message_id)
    await message.add_reaction('<:15:895358200168206367>') #LS
    await message.add_reaction('<:seb:895330238249201725>') #BC
    #Игровая Зона
    await message.add_reaction('<:10:895358262139039764>')#8am
    await message.add_reaction('<:11:895358263456067585>')#3pm
    await message.add_reaction('<:12:895358264286511155>')#8PM
    await message.add_reaction('<:1_:895358254396371005>')#1am
    # ВРЕМЯ
    await message.add_reaction('<:2_:895358262269071441>') #Ясно
    await message.add_reaction('<:3_:895358257735016479>') #Шторм
    await message.add_reaction('<:4_:895358262185173013>') #Облачно
    await message.add_reaction('<:5_:895358257047167006>') #Пасмурно
    #ПОГОДА
    await message.add_reaction('<:6_:895358259337236512>')#15
    await message.add_reaction('<:7_:895358262730424330>')#25
    await message.add_reaction('<:8_:895358263116304484>')#33
    #Температура
    

async def getmsg():
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID КАНАЛА) #!!!
    message = await channel.fetch_message(channel.last_message_id)
    rizused = False
    rtused = False
    rwused = False
    rtempused = False
    time = None
    if message.reactions[0].count > message.reactions[1].count:
        iz = "Los Santos"
    elif message.reactions[1].count > message.reactions[0].count:
        iz = "Blaine County"
    if message.reactions[0].count == message.reactions[1].count:
        izlist = ['Los Santos', 'Blaine County']
        riz = random.choice(izlist)
        rizused = True


    ## Время
    if message.reactions[2].count > max(message.reactions[3].count, message.reactions[4].count, message.reactions[5].count):
        time = "8:00 AM"
    if message.reactions[3].count > max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[4].count, message.reactions[5].count):
        time = "3:00 PM"
    if message.reactions[4].count > max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[3].count, message.reactions[5].count):
        time = "8:00 PM"
    if message.reactions[5].count > max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[3].count, message.reactions[4].count):
        time = "1:00 AM"
    if message.reactions[5].count == max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[4].count, message.reactions[3].count) and message.reactions[4].count == max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[3].count, message.reactions[5].count) and message.reactions[3].count == max(message.reactions[2].count, message.reactions[4].count, message.reactions[5].count) and message.reactions[2].count == max(message.reactions[3].count, message.reactions[4].count, message.reactions[5].count):
        times = ["3:00 PM","8:00 PM","8:00 AM","1:00 AM"]
        rt = random.choice(times)
        rtused = True

    ## Погода

    if message.reactions[6].count > max(message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[8].count, message.reactions[9].count):
        weather = "Ясно"
    if message.reactions[7].count > max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[8].count, message.reactions[9].count):
        weather = "Шторм"
    if message.reactions[8].count > max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[9].count):
        weather = "Облачно"
    if message.reactions[9].count > max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[8].count):
        weather = "Пасмурно"
    if message.reactions[6].count == max(message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[8].count, message.reactions[9].count) and message.reactions[7].count == max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[8].count, message.reactions[9].count) and message.reactions[8].count == max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[9].count) and message.reactions[9].count == max(message.reactions[6].count, message.reactions[7].count, message.reactions[8].count):
        weathers = ["Ясно","Шторм","Облачно","Пасмурно"]
        rw = random.choice(weathers)
        rwused = True

    ## Температура
    if message.reactions[10].count > max(message.reactions[11].count, message.reactions[12].count):
        temp = "15°С (59 °F)"
    if message.reactions[11].count > max(message.reactions[10].count, message.reactions[12].count):
        temp = "25°C (77 °F)"
    if message.reactions[12].count > max(message.reactions[10].count, message.reactions[11].count):
        temp = "33°C (91°F)"
    if message.reactions[10].count == max(message.reactions[11].count, message.reactions[12].count) and message.reactions[11].count == max(message.reactions[10].count, message.reactions[12].count) and message.reactions[12].count == max(message.reactions[10].count, message.reactions[11].count):
        temps = ["15°С (59 °F)","25°C (77 °F)","33°C (91°F)"]
        rtemp = random.choice(temps)
        rtempused = True






    if rizused == True:
        iz = riz
    if rtused == True:
        time = rt
    if rwused == True:
        weather = rw
    if rtempused == True:
        temp = rtemp


    mesg = ("""@everyone 
    В 18.00 по МСК объявлена игровая сессия"""
    """
     Игровая зона —  """ + iz +

    """
      Время — """ + time +


    """
    ☀️ Погода — """ + weather +

    """
    ️ Температура — """ + temp +

    """
    ️ Удачной сессии""")

    await channel.send(mesg)
    print("""@everyone 
        В 18.00 по МСК объявлена игровая сессия"""
        """
         Игровая зона —  """ + iz +

        """
          Время — """ + time +

        """
        ☀️ Погода — """ + weather +

        """
        ️ Температура — """ + temp +

        """
        ️ Удачной сессии"""

        + str(rtused) + str(rizused) + str(rwused) + str(rtempused))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

    #initializing scheduler
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    #sends "текст" to the channel when time hits
    scheduler.add_job(func, CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="17", minute="38", second="00"))

    scheduler.add_job(getmsg, CronTrigger(year="*", month="*", day="*", hour="17", minute="39", second="00"))

    #starting the scheduler
    scheduler.start()



bot.run("ТОКЕН")
```